# Load multiple i18n properties into an array possible? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, properties, sapui5

I have to load multiple I18N-properties that have the same sharing content into an array. I've tried

```
arrayIDs = oBundle.getText().includes(".id.");
```

It said that it can't read the property 'includes' of undefined. Most likely because there isn't anything in getText(). But this has to be variable. This method is made for one property, is there something where I can get multiple properties?

edit: nvm I solved it... If you have the same problem: I discovered

```
oBundle.aPropertyFiles[0].getKeys();
```

for myself and this gets all the keys of the I18N properties you need. After that you can make oBundle.getText(key) to get the according text and implement your own filtering logic.

Comment: What is `oBundle` What is `getText`? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, oBundle is a SAPUI5 library for I18N properties, and getText() is a method in there where the i18n property can be accessed with a given key --> https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/module:sap/base/i18n/ResourceBundle#methods/sap/base/i18n/ResourceBundle.create

Comment: Useful information